# How to reproduce the post format field in a front end form?

Tags: forms, front-end, post-formats

I am looking for a php snippet to display the field "post format" of the wordpress admin in a front end form. It is a conditional field, and some of them need to have a special output (ex: gallery format). It is quite complicated to reproduce at my level.

[image: The post format field]

I didn't find anything about this subject, but I guess that I am not the first one who tries to do this. Thank you very much for your help.

Best regards